# How to connect MS Access database from a network in vb.net 2005

Tags: vb.net

I want to connect an access dabase from a central server using vb.net 2005.Can you help me? please.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the fact that Access really shouldn't be used as a shared DB, you should be able to use direct file access. UNC paths should be enough:

```
\\ServerName\path to .mdb
```